# Tying probability of factors together

Tags: probability

I am new to this community and just have a very simple question.

I want to work out the probability of someone choosing an option (say yes or no). There are different factors affecting their likelihood of picking yes or no e.g.

Factor 1
Foo - chance of yes 80%
Bar - chance of yes 60%
Baz - chance of yes 30%

Factor 2
X - chance of yes 80%
Y - chance of yes 65%
Z - chance of yes 5%

Factor 3
Apple - chance of yes 50%
Orange - chance of yes 30%
Pear - chance of yes 1%

So if we know that someone is Foo, X, Apple, the chances of them picking yes is almost certain (98%?) But I can't work out a simple formula to calculate this.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Apologies in advance if the format of this question is incorrect.

Comment: I think we lack information: we would need the whole variance-covariance matrix of the three factors, not only their marginal probabilities...

Comment: I don't see why additional information is required? Each person has a state for each of the factors, and each of those factors alone determines there statistical probability of choosing an option.

E.g. if you are a foo you have 80% chance of picking yes. If you are an x you have 80% change of picking yes. So if you are both, the overall chance of you picking yes increases to 96%?

That is the logic, but I can't work out how to combine the factors.

Comment: Would be enough if the three factors were independant, but it seems they are not ($Pr(Z|Pear)>Pr(Z)$ for instance)

Comment: Why are they not independant? You can be either of the options for each factor, just each one statistically has a % of your likelihood of picking yes or no.

Like the reasons for picking yes can differ completely for each factor, rather than being tied together? If that makes sense?

Comment: You cannot reason that way. Imagine a simpler case: factor 1: Men - chance of yes 50% Women - chance of yes 50% ; factor 2: Old - chance of yes 50% Young - chance of yes 50%. Obviously neither young men nor old women have a chance of yes of 75%...

Comment: Or in your example, what would be the chances of option yes in case of (Foo,Y,Pear) ?

Comment: Okay so change my scenario to voting for something. Factor 1 is say income band, factor 2 age band and factor 3 level of education. Why could you not then work out the likelihood of someone who is degree educated; 25-40 and earning 30k-40k a year voting yes or no, based on knowing the statistical probabilities of each factor?

Comment: If you also tell me the structure of the population (how many people are in each income band crossed with each age band and with level of education), then I can answer the problem. Otherwise, it possible (in general) to built two different behaviours of voters that will both respect the odds per factor that your require but given distinct odds per triplet of factors.

Comment: I think I understand why it could not be accurate (based on demographic variance), but I don't understand why it is not possible to come up with a formula based on "all things being equal", that would indicate overall likelihood of picking an option based on knowing the % chance of each of those factors?